# How to set different data onto a fragment/viewpager

Tags: android, xamarin, android-viewpager, fragment, fragmentpageradapter

I've looked around but couldn't find any solutions, so this is my last resort.

I'm working on a Xamarin-Android project and I've got a viewpager with one fragment. The trick with this fragment is that even though it's only one fragment, it loads many instances of this one fragment, depending on how many I need but the problem is that each fragment needs to load one object (one set of data). The problem I have is that when I iterate through the list of returned items (loaded from a file), it obviously loops through everything and sets the last set of returned data onto my fragment. This causes me to have many fragments with the same data. What I need is to load one set of data onto each fragment instead of it loading the last set onto my fragment. So in essence, I have one fragment which loads many instances and each instance needs to show one object's data. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Okay, please see below - This is the fragment class. I've left out the OnCreateView of the fragment, as it only inflates the fragment resource and gets the textviews etc. Let me know if you need the FragmentPagerAdapter code as well. This one fragment has many instances, which is set in the FragmentPagerAdapter class in the Count and GetItem overidden methods. Count returns the number of instances required and GetItem which does "return ThisFragment.newInstance(position);"

EDIT: Code updated with solution

```
private int mNum;
private string code, status;
TextView textviewMyObjectCode, textviewMyObjectStatus;

public static ThisFragment newInstance(int num)
{
    ThisFragment myFragment = new ThisFragment();
    MyObject myObject = new MyObject();

    List<MyObject> myObjectList = MyObjectIO.LoadMyObjectsFromFile();

    myObject.MyObjectNumber = myObjectList[num].MyObjectNumber;
    myObject.MyObjectStatus = myObjectList[num].MyObjectStatus;

    args.PutInt("num", num);
    args.PutString("objectCode", myObject.MyObjectNumber);
    args.PutString("objectStatus", myObject.MyObjectStatus);

    myFragment.Arguments = args;

    return thisFragment;
}

public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mNum = Arguments != null ? Arguments.GetInt("num") : 1;
    code = Arguments.GetString("objectCode");
    status = Arguments.GetString("objectStatus");          
}

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       if (container == null)
       {
         return null;
       }

       View thisView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.object_fragment, container, false);

       textviewObjectStatus = thisView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textviewObjectStatus);
       textviewObjectCode = thisView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textviewObjectCode);

       textviewObjectCode.Text = code;
       textviewObjectStatus.Text = status;

       return thisView;
   }
```

Comment: You need to post the code otherwise difficult to suggest a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Do you need the code for the whole project or just the snippet that gets the data from the file and loads it onto the fragment?

Comment: Not the whole project..Just the snippet of code which deals with fragment.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm trying to post my code here but it's complaining that it's too long. Just gimme a min.

Comment: Can you post the code in your main question so that you can format it correctly?

Comment: @Jay: Thanks, I've added it to the opening post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. Since I am using the newInstance method, which contains a position variable called "num" and because I get a list of objects from the LoadObjectsFromFile method, I can assign a specific object to a specific fragment. Example: I can load object[0] onto fragment[0]. I do this in the  newInstance method, set the values to a Bundle and then retrieve it later in OnCreate. Then in OnCreateView, I can place the values onto my textviews. @Jay, I now realize what you were saying all along. It didn't click initially :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be the responsibility of the 'FragmentPagerAdapter' to create new Fragments. You seem to have delegated this responsibility to a Fragment class which is not the right approach. Here you are setting text of 'textviewMyObjectCode' and 'textviewMyObjectStatus' again and again in a loop so these values will get over-ridden in every iteration of the loop.
Ideally you should access 'MyObjectList' in 'newInstance' and set the values in Bundle objects as per the index passed in 'num'. Also 'newInstance' should be part of 'FragmentPagerAdapter' and 'MyObjectList' should be available to 'FragmentPagerAdapter'.

If 'ThisFragment' is the Fragment which is needed to be part of ViewPager then that fragment should just do the job of retrieving its data from the Bundle and set the needed data to its resources.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Will take a look tomorrow and see what I need to do there.

Comment: I'm still having some issues with this. Could anyone perhaps share some code that can help me please? (sorry, I'm a noob)